# Erro ao executar o comando 'bcp' dentro de uma procedure

Tags: sql-server, exportação

Quando executo o comando:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000);
SET @cmd = 'bcp "select [colunas] FROM [usuario].dbo.[tabela] " queryout "\\***\SQLServer\text.txt" -c -UTF8 -T -S***';
EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

Funciona. Mas quando executo o mesmo comando dentro de uma ***procedure*** recebo um ***output*** e nada mais, o que devo fazer para esse comando funcionar corretamente na procedure?

**PROCEDURE:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_EXPORTAR_ARQUIVO] 
        @p_funcionalidade nvarchar(50), 
        @ano nvarchar(4) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
    @sqlParaArquivo nvarchar(4000),
    @localArquivo varchar(1000),
    @parametros varchar(1000),
    @nomeArquivo varchar(1000),
    @SERVIDOR varchar(1000),
    @BANCO varchar(1000),
    @comando varchar(1000),
    @cmd varchar(4000);
SELECT @localArquivo = LOCAL_ARQUIVO, @sqlParaArquivo = CONSULTA, @SERVIDOR  = SERVIDOR, @BANCO = BANCO FROM usuario_des.dbo.PARAMETROS_EXPORTAR_ARQUIVO where FUNCIONALIDADE = @p_funcionalidade;
    set @nomeArquivo = COALESCE(@p_funcionalidade,'') + COALESCE(@ano,'') + '.txt';
    set @comando = 'bcp ';
    set @localArquivo = '"'+ COALESCE(@localArquivo,'')+'\' + COALESCE(@nomeArquivo,'') + '"';
    set @parametros = 'queryout ' + COALESCE(@localArquivo,'')  +' -c -UTF8 -T -S'+@SERVIDOR +' -d'+@BANCO;
    set @cmd = @comando + ' "'+COALESCE(@sqlParaArquivo,'') + '" '+ COALESCE(@parametros,'');
    SELECT @cmd ;
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT 
            ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
            ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
    END CATCH;  
END
```

**Retorno:**

```
usage: bcp {dbtable | query} {in | out | queryout | format} datafile
  [-m maxerrors]            [-f formatfile]          [-e errfile]
  [-F firstrow]             [-L lastrow]             [-b batchsize]
  [-n native type]          [-c character type]      [-w wide character type]
  [-N keep non-text native] [-V file format version] [-q quoted identifier]
  [-C code page specifier]  [-t field terminator]    [-r row terminator]
  [-i inputfile]            [-o outfile]             [-a packetsize]
  [-S server name]          [-U username]            [-P password]
  [-T trusted connection]   [-v version]             [-R regional enable]
  [-k keep null values]     [-E keep identity values]
  [-h "load hints"]         [-x generate xml format file]
  [-d database name]
NULL
```

Comment: Tem como colocar o código da procedure? E parece que você substituiu alguns elementos secretor por asterisco. Teria como usar outro símbolo? Fica um pouco confuso já que o asterisco é usado no select e para comentários em bloco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema..
Quando eu busco o select da tabela que eu vou executar,
nele eu formatei a query.

ou seja, existia alguns \n no comando, fazendo com ele não fosse executado.
Por isso ele me apresentava quais são os parâmetros do comando